# Variance of positively recurrent Markov chain hitting time

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

> Consider the following Markov chain:
>   [image]
>   How to compute the variance of $T_{1,0}$ the time to get from state $1$ to state $0$?

Now I can get the stationary distribution $\pi_i=\frac{1}{3}(\frac{2}{3})^i$. Thus we know the the time to get from state k to state k is $m_{kk}=\frac{1}{\pi_k}$.

Also from $m_{0,0}=0.6*m_{0,0}+0.4*(1+m_{1,0})$ we can get $E[T_{1,0}]$.

I think it can be solve using $Var[X]=E[X^2]-(E[X])^2$ but how to get $E[T_{1,0}^2]$?

Answer (score 3):

> (2017-10-24) *Amusing* downvote, purely for mathematical reasons, I am sure...

To reach the higher moments of $T_{1,0}$, one can use the Markov property of the chain after one step, which translates into the identity in distribution $$T_{1,0}=1+B\cdot(T_{2,1}+T'_{1,0})$$ where $B$ is Bernoulli with $P(B=1)=b$ and $P(B=0)=1-b$ for $b=.4$, and $T'_{1,0}$ is distributed like $T_{1,0}$ and independent of $T_{2,1}$.

Since $T_{2,1}$ is also distributed like $T_{1,0}$, one is after the solution of the identity

> $$T\stackrel d=1+B\cdot(T+T')\tag{$\ast$}$$

This allows to recover the first moment $E(T_{1,0})$ since $(\ast)$ implies $$E(T)=1+2b\cdot E(T)$$ hence, using $b<\frac12$, $$E(T)=\frac1{1-2b}$$ but also the second moment since $(\ast)$ also implies $$E(T^2)=1+4b\cdot E(T)+b\cdot(2E(T^2)+2E(T))$$ hence, using again $b<\frac12$, $$E(T^2)=\frac{1+6b\cdot E(T)}{1-2b}=\frac{1+4b}{(1-2b)^2}$$ and finally,

> $$\mathrm{var}(T)=\frac{4b}{(1-2b)^2}$$

Note that, more generally, turning to generating functions rather than moments, $(\ast)$ would allow to reach *distributions* since, for every $s$ in $[0,1]$, $$E(s^T)=s\cdot(1-b+b\cdot E(s^T)^2)$$ hence

> $$E(s^T)=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4b(1-b)s^2}}{2bs}$$

from which the full distribution of $T_{1,0}$ follows.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more on how you imply the second moment equation: $E(T^2)=1+4b⋅E(T)+b⋅(2E(T^2)+2E(T))$ ?

Comment: Guys. I think there's a typo. I think the last term is $b^2(2E(T^2) + 2E(T))$. Maybe that's what's confusing?

Comment: @helen. If you're interested in the derivation of the moment generation function here. You can find it in the book Markov Chains by Norris. Page 21 has a very detailed derivation of this. :)

Comment: @WilmerE.Henao Think harder: $B^2=B$ hence $E(B^2)=b$, not $b^2$.

Comment: @helen Sorry but what is not direct in $$T^2=^d1+2B\cdot(T+T')+B\cdot(T^2+2TT'+T'^2)$$ which implies $$E(T^2)=1+2E(B)\cdot(2E(T))+E(B)\cdot(2E(T^2)+2E(T)^2)\ ?$$